# Quick and dirty loading image

Tags: c#, visual-studio

With a Windows Form Application in Microsoft Visual Studio, how can I display an image while my program is collecting data from a website?

Currently it's set up so when the user clicks a button, that button hits the website to display an image and text. There's a delay in the time it takes it to get that information and I'd just like to display some sort of image to let the user know that they DID in fact click that button and something is happening.

My only solution has been to have the button the user clicks display the image and then have said button 'click' a hidden button to trigger the data collection, but I was told buttons clicking buttons is bad practice (which makes sense). Unfortunately the person who told me not to do it like that didn't offer an alternative.

I am a novice and I apologize. I have been looking around online for a couple days now and everything seems too elaborate for this seemingly simple thing.

Comment: [`BackgroundWorker` FTW](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners).

Comment: Do you have some sample code for your current workflow?

Comment: Use async await example    async void buttonclick(). Then set a GIF or progress bar on in the beginning await your function then turn off the progress bar

Comment: I can't even figure out how to format my comment to display the code nicely. I guess I'll be back when I get a clue. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: What you want to do is simple, but to provide any specific advice, you would need to include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly illustrates your scenario. For sure, you do not want to block the UI thread while you are fetching data, but that's true regardless of whether you display an image or not. So if you've solved that part, all that's left is to show the image when the button is clicked, and remove the image (or replace it with the fetched image+text?) when the data fetching has completed.